# 2-factor authentication for accessing Azure VMs - possible?

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication

My client wants 2FA when accessing VMs in Azure. Is this possible at all? I was thinking about Azure Directory Domain Services, but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: This question is far too broad, do you mean RDP? HTTP? SSH? something else...

Comment: The VM itself supports RDP or SSH out of the box. Anything else is going to be app-specific, and up to you to integrate into your app.

Comment: Back in the day there was http://phonefactor.com which is now absorbed into Azure AD MFA. However it seems to have lost the ability to do 2FA with VMs which it did had and it was darn elegant to work with. This is a good request to post on http://feedback.azure.com

Comment: I meant RDP, sorry. So I don't understand - can 2FA be enabled when RDP to VM in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [Azure Application Proxy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/applicationproxyblog/2015/10/14/publishing-remote-desktop-with-azure-active-directory-application-proxy/) to surface RDP functionality of Azure VMs to the internet.  Application proxy is protected by Azure Active Directory, and thus, you can use 2 factor authentication (if you have the premium SKU) to protect the initial login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service such as Duo Security for Windows VMs.

For ssh 2FA to Linux VM, you can use [Google Authenticator PAM module library](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki/PAM-Module-Instructions)